# Is it possible to automatically configure APN settings?

Tags: gps, gprs, apn

I'm using an [A6 GSM module](https://m.ebay.com/itm/A6-GPRS-GSM-Module-Adapter-Board-Plate-Quad-band-850-900-1800-1900MHZ-Antenna/322121300920?_mwBanner=1&_rdt=1) to connect a microcontroller to a server over the Internet. I noticed that I have to manually configure the APN settings for each SIM card I use.

So, is it possible to automatically configure these settings? How does a mobile phone do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is not possible. Phones have a database with APN settings from many (but not all) providers. A solution could be to use a carrier agnostic network: https://hologram.io.